# Eclipse crashes on first run ( See the .log file)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having a problem running eclipse.

Everytime i try to set the workspace, the program crashes saying to check the log file.

I already tried to erase the workspace folder and run the application using the "- clean " command and no progress. Please help

Log File:

```
!SESSION 2013-09-05 18:09:23.056 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v22.0.5-757759
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pt_PT
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-09-05 18:09:33.571
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.net (83).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.net.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2558)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$7(Workbench.java:2441)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at      org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.open(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.getDefault(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault(SecurePreferencesFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getNode(ProxyType.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.loadProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.createProxyData(ProxyType.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getProxyData(ProxyType.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrateInstanceScopePreferences(PreferenceManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrate(PreferenceManager.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.checkMigrated(ProxyManager.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start(Activator.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 54 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.open(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.getDefault(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault(SecurePreferencesFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getNode(ProxyType.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.loadProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.createProxyData(ProxyType.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getProxyData(ProxyType.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrateInstanceScopePreferences(PreferenceManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrate(PreferenceManager.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.checkMigrated(ProxyManager.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start(Activator.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2558)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$7(Workbench.java:2441)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 54 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-09-05 18:09:33.627
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.net (83).
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2558)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$7(Workbench.java:2441)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at     org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Look at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=406034 about the 3rd comment down states a fix

Answer (score -2):

Not an expert but I had a very similar experience.

My problem was that eclipse and jdk were not installed in their default locations. Once I corrected it, this worked.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have a "default" location, it can be run from desktop if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

I read the thread on bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=406034 and i found out the solution to the problem and it was by uninstalling all java applications and reinstall them again.